# Required bean of type PubsubOutboundGateway' that could not be found, work with springboot 2.7 but not with springboot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I trying to use GCP PUB/SUB with springboot 3. I am using example from [Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-gcp-pubsub/)
I have config class

```
@Configuration
public class PubSubConfig {

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubsubOutputChannel")
    public MessageHandler messageSender(PubSubTemplate pubsubTemplate) {
        return new PubSubMessageHandler(
                pubsubTemplate, "check");
    }
    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "pubsubOutputChannel")
    public interface PubsubOutboundGateway {
        void sendToPubsub(String text);
    }
}
```

I am trying to inject in my service class

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyService{
  private final PubSubConfig.PubsubOutboundGateway gateway;
```

But the application can't start when I use

```
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.6</version>
```

I have `required a bean of type '....PubSubConfig$PubsubOutboundGateway' that could not be found`
It's working with `<version>2.7.6</version>`

Comment: I fix it with `@IntegrationComponentScan` , still need to check if the message are realy post to my local pubsub emulator